# Xcode: How to get page up and page down to move cursor?

Tags: xcode

This is a mac thing (because text edit does the same) but I just want to change this in xcode.

I'd like the cursor to move when I hit the page-up and page-down button. Kind of like the way windows or linux work. I know I can hold down the "option" button and then go page-up, page-down and it works
 - but I don't want to hold the option button.

I tried fiddling around with key bindings in xcode but couldn't get it, anyone know how?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In preferences, go to key bindings, type "page" in the search box, look for Page Down (Selection) / Page Up (Selection), click there and hit your pgdn/pgup keys.

Delete the pgdn/pgup keys from Scroll Page Up/Down.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 10):

Whit **Xcode 6.1** (and >) is quite different, but similar to Colin's answer.

```
Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings
```

Search for **"Move Page Up"**: by default it's bindend with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>

You can change your binding simply with <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

There may be conflicts, resolve it is suggested.

Than repeat the same for **"Move Page Down"**.

Comment: "He had found a Nutri-Matic machine which had provided him with a plastic cup filled with a liquid that was almost, but not quite, entirely unlike tea." - Douglas Adams. (Re "... is quite different, but similar to ...")  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) and life will be good. If you have a PC/Mac/Linux environment the MacOS keyboard inconsistencies can be a real pain.  We have all of our Macs setup to work as PC keyboards work.  Now switching from one system to the other several times a day is not a problem.

Comment: I use BetterTouchTool to emulate emacs-like chord sequences, like "^+x 0", "^x ^o", etc, mapped to XCode specifically.